# Extract day of week using perl and mysql date format

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime

I am looping through a range of consecutive dates. I need to find out which are weekends so they can be discarded. One method would be to determine the day of week via perl (what my script is written in) or query with each pass through the loop. There will never be more than 30 dates, usually 5 or less to check. Would it be more efficient to load up Date::Time and use perl or run a Query without needing modules? If perl is the best method I could use a little help extracting the day of week from the YYYY-MM-DD format. I'd be ok with number 1-7 or shortname mon-sun.

```
2012-05-01
2012-05-02
2012-05-03
2012-05-04
2012-05-05
2012-05-06
```

not sure if this is possible but perhaps a more suitable solution would be to write a query (since I know the start and end and they are consecutive) to count days between x and y where dayofweek NOT IN(6,7)

Comment: Since the dates are consecutive, once you know the week day of the first date, it's trivial to find the first weekend and know that all other weekends occur 7 days later.

Comment: I still have to loop through this list of dates (dates exists in a text file, not pulled from a query) my end goal is to have a total count of week days in a range. the rage could start on any day of the month. I don't see how your answer addresses my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Date::Simple qw/date/;
use Date::Range;

my ( $start, $end ) = ( date('2012-05-02'), date('2012-05-16') );
my $range = Date::Range->new( $start, $end );
my @all_dates = $range->dates;

foreach my $d (@all_dates) {
  my $date  = Date::Simple->new($d);
  print $date->day_of_week." ".$d."<br />";
  }

#--OUTPUT--#

3 2012-05-02
4 2012-05-03
5 2012-05-04
6 2012-05-05
0 2012-05-06
1 2012-05-07
2 2012-05-08
3 2012-05-09
4 2012-05-10
5 2012-05-11
6 2012-05-12
0 2012-05-13
1 2012-05-14
2 2012-05-15
3 2012-05-16
```

Answer (score 3):

See [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) and [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime).

```
use 5.010;
use strictures;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw();
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%F');
for my $date (qw(
    2012-05-01
    2012-05-02
    2012-05-03
    2012-05-04
    2012-05-05
    2012-05-06
)) {
    my $dow = $parser->parse_datetime($date)->day_of_week;
    say "$date is a weekend day" if 6 == $dow or 7 == $dow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a [day of week function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) you can use directly.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious solution is to use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module, which has been a core module of Perl since v5.9 and so probably doesn't need installing on your system.

The `wday` method returns a numeric day of week where 1 == Sunday, so for the weekend you are looking for values of 7 (Saturday) or 1. This can be adjusted so that Saturday is represented by zero instead (and Sunday by 1) by writing

```
my $dow = $tp->wday % 7;
```

after which the test for a weekend is simply `$dow < 2`.

Here is some code to demonstrate.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d');
  my $dow = $tp->wday % 7;
  print $_;
  print " (weekend)" if $dow < 2;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
2012-05-01
2012-05-02
2012-05-03
2012-05-04
2012-05-05
2012-05-06
```

**output**

```
2012-05-01
2012-05-02
2012-05-03
2012-05-04
2012-05-05 (weekend)
2012-05-06 (weekend)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the core [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) module and then compute the weekday using [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). Weekday 0 corresponds to Sunday, and 6 is Saturday.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;

my @dates = qw(
  2012-05-01
  2012-05-02
  2012-05-03
  2012-05-04
  2012-05-05
  2012-05-06
);

my @days = qw/ Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat /;

foreach my $date (@dates) {
  my($yyyy,$mm,$dd) = split /-/, $date;
  my $time_t = timelocal 0, 0, 0, $dd, $mm-1, $yyyy-1900;
  my $wday = (localtime $time_t)[6];
  my $weekend = ($wday == 0 || $wday == 6) ? " *" : "";

  print "$date: $days[$wday] ($wday)$weekend\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2012-05-01: Tue (2)
2012-05-02: Wed (3)
2012-05-03: Thu (4)
2012-05-04: Fri (5)
2012-05-05: Sat (6) *
2012-05-06: Sun (0) *
```

For fun, you could go Swiss Army Chainsaw and scrape the output of the *cal* utility.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;  # for smart matching

sub weekday_type {
  my($date) = @_;
  die "$0: unexpected date '$date'"
    unless my($yyyy,$mm,$dd) =
             $date =~ /^([0-9]{1,4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})$/;

  my $calendar = `cal -m $mm $yyyy`;
  die "$0: cal -m $mm $yyyy failed" if $?;

  for (split /\n/, $calendar) {
    if (/^ \s* [0-9]{1,2} (?: \s+ [0-9]{1,2})* \s*$/x) {
      my @dates = split;
      my @weekend = splice @dates, @dates > 1 ? -2 : -1;
      return "weekend" if ($dd+0) ~~ @weekend;
    }
  }

  "weekday";
}
```

Use it as in

```
my @dates = qw(
  2012-05-01
  2012-05-02
  2012-05-03
  2012-05-04
  2012-05-05
  2012-05-06
);

my @days = qw/ Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat /;

foreach my $date (@dates) {
  my $type = weekday_type $date;
  print "$date: $type\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2012-05-01: weekday
2012-05-02: weekday
2012-05-03: weekday
2012-05-04: weekday
2012-05-05: weekend
2012-05-06: weekend
```

I don’t recommend doing it this way in production.